# VB.Net TableAdapter versus BindingSource in Database

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataset

I fail to understand the roles of TableAdapters and BindingSource in VB.NET database handling. It seems to me they perform the same operation. I have read every piece of information from MSDN to each an every Q&A online but I can't seem to differentiate their roles. When and when not to use TableAdapters or BindingSource? It will be more comprehensive if one can give a solution with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different things.

A [TableAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171919.aspx) basically maps data from a database table into a [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0sdh0b(v=vs.110).aspx).

> A TableAdapter component fills a dataset with data from the database,
>   based on one or more queries or stored procedures that you specify.
>   TableAdapters can also perform adds, updates, and deletes on the
>   database to persist changes that you make to the dataset. You can also
>   issue global commands that are unrelated to any specific table.

A [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxxf124e(v=vs.110).aspx) is a .NET component which can be used for Data Binding for a control to a datasource like a DataSet.

> The BindingSource component is designed to simplify the process of
>   **binding controls to an underlying data source**. The BindingSource
>   component acts as both a conduit and a data source for other controls
>   to bind to. It provides an abstraction of your form's data connection
>   while passing through commands to the underlying list of data.
>   Additionally, you can add data directly to it, so that the component
>   itself functions as a data source.

[Database To Typed-DataSet, With BindingSource Example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/344306-database-to-typed-dataset-with-bindingsource/)

[A Detailed Data Binding Tutorial Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

Comment: This is simply comprehensive . Just for a little follow up. Can INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE be done to a BindingSource and Then use TableAdapter to commit the changes in the BindingSource to the raw Database permanently? How can this be achieved? Demonstrate with lines of Code for concrete understanding

Comment: @K1b1w077 I've edited my answer and provided links to two complete examples - it would be a lot of code to paste into SO. The point is that, TableAdapter and BindingSource are different things. One is a "map" between your database and DataSet and another is for databinding.